# Unexpected value 'steps' in azure-pipelines.yml

Tags: azure-pipelines-yaml

Pipeline validation fails with `Unexpected value 'steps' in acr-login.yaml`. Even I tribble-checked the docs and stackoverflows, I can't find the issue in my pipeline:

`pipeline.yaml`

```yaml
trigger: none
pool:
  name: MyPool
variables:
  - template: vars/global.yaml
  - template: vars/stage.yaml

stages:
  - stage: Import
    jobs:
      - template: steps/acr-login.yaml
        parameters:
          registry_name: ${{variables.registry_name}}
```

`acr-login.yaml`

```yaml
parameters:
  - name: registry_name
    type: string
steps:
- bash: |
    az login --identity --output none
    az acr login --name ${{ parameters.registry_name }} --output none
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your acr-login.yaml must contain (one or multible) jobs since you are using it as job template:

```
parameters:
- name: registry_name
  type: string
jobs: 
- job: myStep
  steps:
  - bash: |
      az login --identity --output none
      az acr login --name ${{ parameters.registry_name }} --output none
```

Comment: that made the trick, thank you!